# Wordpress not executing mysql_query()

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have updated an old version of Wordpress (3.0.1) to 4.4.2. Everything works, except for one plugin, which has all queries in this style. I have used a custom page to test a simple query and can verify that the query returns nothing:

```
$query = "SELECT code FROM wp_kk_video WHERE id = '0'";
$result = mysql_query ($query);
```

Then I replaced that query with the following:

```
$query = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT code FROM wp_kk_video WHERE id = '0'" );
$result = $query->code;
```

And it worked perfectly.

So why has Wordpress stopped executing the old type of `mysql_query` queries?

Comment: Which Php version r u using?

Comment: Use PHP 5.3+ or 5.4+ (PHP 5.5+ PHP 5.6+ PHP 7.0+ PHP 7.1+ is not supported for now)

Comment: `mysql_query` is deprecated, FYI. Have you tried using `mysqli_query()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mysql_* has been deprecated and now its not available in newer versions of Php.

**Suggestions:**

Use PHP 5.3+ or 5.4+ (PHP 5.5+ PHP 5.6+ PHP 7.0+ PHP 7.1+ is not supported for now).

Or use `mysqli_*` extension for WordPress 4.4.

Or in the last change queries as per wordpress `$wpdb->get_row`.

**[PHP Unsupported Branches](http://php.net/eol.php)**

**[WordPress Forum](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/ugly-errors-on-wordpress-441-make-it-unusable)**

**[Wpdb Class References:](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)**

Answer (score 2):

Plugins should always use the [wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) class/variable abstraction, so that updates like yours don't break your blog as Wordpress code already looks which mysql* functions are available.

Also they offer prepared statements which should be used to prevent SQL injection attacks. If the id parameter in your example is a user provided value and therefore possible evil input, you should rewrite it to the following to be on the secure side:

```
$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( 
    "SELECT code FROM wp_kk_video WHERE id = '%d'", 
    $video_id
) );
```